# no whitespaces between identifiers in colab notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory

It's my first time using google colab notebook.
The code here have no whitespaces to separate keywords, but only different colors.

I've seen other colabs having whitespaces between the keywords. My issue is with the design I'm getting. I want spaces between keywords like in other Ipython notebooks. My colab notebook looks like:
[Screenshot from my Colab notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87SY6.png)

Someone help my find the solution.

Comment: Which font family is listed in the menu under Tools-Settings-Editor-Code font?

Comment: @Marijn It's monospace. Now, I tried it changing to consolas and got spaces between keywords. Then, I tried with other fonts as well and that worked too.